# Software that tells you which song file has the best quality

Tags: audio

I have a song in 3 different formats. Honestly I can't hear any difference between them, but I would like to store only the file that has the best quality **because in future I could play it on a high quality speaker**

Is there a software or a web app where I can to upload the files and it tells me which one has the best quality objectively?

Comment: You could probably analyse and compare via https://www.audacityteam.org/ . You'd have to import all three and compare.

Comment: @ZZ - 'compare'…. how, using what?

Comment: Visually looking at waves/freq and by ear :) As far as I know, there is no way to compare automatically as it also depends on original source of each one. If original was direct from CD to a lossless source (e.g. WAV or FLAC), then you could convert to any format. But if originals were from lossy format like mp3, then any conversion will still be lossy.

Comment: @ZZ - this question actually has quite a history, starting on [sound design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/51654/9601), then [super user](https://superuser.com/q/1739995/347380) & finally here, as a last resort. I know of no way to do this automatically, nor even by staring at a waveform/spectrograph in an editor. My opinion still stands that if you can't tell the difference & don't know which is closest to source, keep the smallest.

Comment: I agree with picking one closest to source. Didn't know question has history. :)